# How to click a button and open all links in an unordered list in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'd like to have a button that if clicked will click() all the links in a specific unordered list.

```
<ul id="linkslist">
    <li><a href="#" target="_blank">Link 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" target="_blank">Link 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" target="_blank">Link 3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" target="_blank">Link 4</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" target="_blank">Link 5</a></li>
</ul>
<button value="open all" id="openallbutton">
```

I realize that this example in itself probably could be done with simple javascript, but since I'm going to expand on this with jQuery I'd prefer to use jQuery for this example. Thanks so much.

Comment: This sounds like an XY-problem http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem . Why do you want to click all the links? Shouldn't you just call the function that is attached to them?

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like that :

```
jQuery('#linkslist li a').each(function(){
   //if you want to open links in new tabs
   window.open($(this).attr('href'), '_blank');
   //if your links are only javascript entries (i mean href="#" and a click event is handled)
   $(this).click();
});
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$('#linkslist li a').each(function(){
    $(this).click();
});
```

This will click them. If you are not attaching events to the clicks and they have a link in the href, obviously, you will just be redirected to a single link.

Answer (score -1):

What is the purpose of opening all these links at once? Has the opportunity to be seen as malicious activity.

To 'trigger' the click on each link you could do the following:

```
$('#linkslist li a').each(function() {
    $(this).trigger('click');
});
```

This is asking for problems though and I'm pretty certain this won't actually open the page as it will try and click each link programmatically.

Comment: Problem : if there is no target attribute specified on the link and if href is an url, it will open only the first link in the same window.

Answer (score -1):

This will click them all by clciking on the button....if you want them to open in other window, a programmed click won't do that and will have to parse each `href` to do it

```
/* button clcik*/
$('#openallbutton').click(function(){
    /* trigger click on all links*/
    $('#linkslist li a').click();
})
```